# Inverse of an integer computed with CRT

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose I have prime numbers $p_1...p_n$ and $x_0 = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i$. Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, compute $$y=CRT_{p_i}({y_i})$$ for some $y_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$. In the above equation $y$ is defined modulo $x_0$.

**My question.** Is always $y$ invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_{x_0}$ ?

**My thinking.** It is well known that CRT is an insomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_n}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{x_0}
$. As the inverse of $y \pmod{p_i}$ exists in each $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$, the isomorphism keeps this property also in $\mathbb{Z}_{x_0}$. So $y$ has to be invertible $\pmod{x_0}$.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem works (and may be useful) when one (or several) $y_0$ are $0$, too. Then, $y$ is still defined modulo $x_0,$ but not invertible.

Comment: Assume that $y_i$ is not zero, $\forall i=\overline{1,n}$

Comment: Then, it's invertible, and $y^{-1}=CRT_{p_i}(y^{-1}_i)$, naturally.